# OpenGL sampler2D as argument into subroutine method causes error

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a subroutine method in GLSL fragment shader which should output pixel based on sampler2D as input argument.The program fails to compile with this setup.However the method works fine as long as I output just a color without texure2D() calculation.
Is it possible that sampler2D can't be passed as parameter.I am working with OpenGL 4.2,GLSL 420

Here is the code:

```
#version 420
subroutine vec4 RenderPass(sampler2D tex,vec2 uvsIn);
subroutine uniform RenderPass renderTechnique;
layout(binding=0)  uniform sampler2D colorMap;
smooth in vec2 uvsOut;

 ........ there rest of stuff

subroutine( RenderPass )
vec4 copyPass(sampler2D tex,vec2 uvsIn){


  return texture2D(tex,uvsIn);
  ////this however works ok : return vec4(1,0,0,1);

}

void main()
{

    outputColor = renderTechnique(colorMap,uvsOut);


}
```

UPDATE:
Ok ,thanks for  the headups .I fixed shader compile logs.Now I am getting this program error:

```
: error C5208: Sampler needs to be a uniform (global or parameter to main), need to inline function or resolve conditional expression
```

Comment: "The program fails to compile with this setup." What error did you get?

Comment: Doing it via Java (LWJGL) wrapper.Can't retrieve program compile errors.But does it work in C++ based environment ? For now I just decoded to access the sampler2D uniform directly without passing it as argument.

Comment: @MichaelIV according to [this](http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/ARBShaderObjects.html) you should be able to call the shader info log through lwjgl

Comment: @KillianDS ,you are right but somehow the error buffer in LWJGL always returns nothing.

Comment: @KillianDS: That function is only for ARB_shader_objects, which you should never use. What you're looking for is the core 2.0 [`glGetProgramInfoLog`](http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL20.html#glGetProgramInfoLog%28int,%20int%29).

Comment: @MichaelIV: Then you need to fix *that*. Getting proper infologs is a big part of developing with GLSL.

Comment: @NicolBolas I know that, but maybe I do not know lwjgl enough, thought they  maybe used arb_shader_objects throughout the whole instead of core.

Comment: See my update.Does it basically mean I can't pass sampler2D uniform as param ?

Comment: This works without a problem in my engine. I'm using GLSL version 120. I don't get a single compilation warning. My GPU is an Nvidia GTX 460.